# Is there a faster way for the VBA macro to execute my formula?

Tags: excel, vba, execution-time, maxifs

I created a macro and I'm using the following way to calculate the maximum value:

```
UltimaLinha = Workbooks(modelo).Sheets(NomeAba).Cells(Workbooks(modelo).Sheets(NomeAba).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("V5:V" & UltimaLinha)

rng.Formula = "=IFERROR(MAXIFS(matriz_de_custos!$P$2:$P$" & UltimaLinha_mc & ",matriz_de_custos!$L$2:$L$" & UltimaLinha_mc & ",RC[-18],matriz_de_custos!$U$2:$U$" & UltimaLinha_mc & ",RC[-17],matriz_de_custos!$D$2:$D$" & UltimaLinha_mc & ",RC[-12]),0)"

rng.Value = rng.Value
```

But as I need to do this operation several times, the macro is taking a long time to execute... Is there a better or faster way to execute this process?

I just tried using batch calculation, which was the code I posted.

Comment: Side note: why are you mixing A1 and R1C1 notation in your formula?

Comment: It might help if you add `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` at the beginning and `Application.ScreenUpdating` at the end. This type of macro tends to do a lot of screen updates, if the range is large.

Comment: Where do you define `UltimaLinha_mc`?

Comment: Rather, `Application.EnableEvents` to prevent the workbook from recalculating when replacing the formula with the values. Anyway, what is your exact version of Excel? Do you have the `LET` function? what about the `FILTER` function?

Comment: 'UltimaLinha_matcust = Workbooks(modelo).Sheets("matriz_de_custos").Cells(Workbooks(modelo).Sheets("matriz_de_custos").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'

Comment: My excel version is 2308